# Python script for automating GCP storage UPLOAD

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, file-upload, automation, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to GCP and GCP Storage. I want to upload files from File System on PC to GCS bucket.
I found following code and altering it.

But I have files that sit in folder like this: `\F1\Data\Export\PlayOnUsers\2021\12\`
That is 2021 year and 12 month - December

So after `\F1\Data\Export\PlayOnUsers\` it's changing.

I need to put in similar format to GCS. I need to create sub-buckets `2021\` and `12\`

How is this done?
I also don't see the part where you put CREDENTIALS FOR GCS

I have this code so far:

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    
    
    def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
        """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
        # The ID of your GCS bucket
        bucket_name = "MyBucket-scv"
    
        # The path to your file to upload
        source_file_name = "F1/Data/Export"
    
        # The ID of your GCS object
        destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    
        blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
    
        print(
            "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
                source_file_name, destination_blob_name
            )
        )
    
    upload_blob(.., .., ..)

# how do I pass parameters automated when calling the function?
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Finding Credentials Automatically](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically). Using these "Application Default Credentials" is a good practice. All you need do is have a Service Account with suitable role|permissions and, if you're running off-GCP (i.e. not on Compute Engine etc.), then you'll need to create a Service Account key and reference it `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` **before** you run your code.

Google Cloud Storage (GCS) does not really have a concept of folders nor "sub-buckets". In fact, everything in a GCS bucket is called an Object **but** Object names may include `/` (this is the *nix equivalent of Windows' `/`) and commonly (!) used to denote folder paths.

So, you only really have to worry about recursively iterating over your Windows folders (I'll leave that to you) and then for **every** file that your code finds, it will need to create an Object in your GCS bucket that comprises:

1. The bucket
2. The folder structures with `/` instead of `\`
3. The filename

i.e.

- `\F1|Data\Export\PlayOnUsers\2021\12\x` becomes `gs://your-bucket/F1/Data/Exporter/PlayOnUsers/2021/12/x`
- `\F1|Data\Export\PlayOnUsers\2022\01\x` becomes `gs://your-bucket/F1/Data/Exporter/PlayOnUsers/2022/01/x`

Comment: Thank you! I got it about Objects. After a few attempts I have a correct code. `destination_blob_name = "Consumption/" + os.path.split(source_file_name)[-1]` . Makes "Object". Depending on file name I will be putting them to different folders. Think that now I don't need "/2021/12/" anymore. If I already have "Consumption/" in my Bucket will it just put file in already existing Object "Consumption"?

Comment: Sorry, to be clear. I just found out that all files sit in one Folder and will need to be put in different folders due to the file names

Comment: Then you want to parse the filenames and inject `/` to mimic the folder structure, i.e. `2021-12-31.doc` becomes `gs://bucket/.../2021/12/31/doc` or similar.